# How to solve python POST response 405

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-api-gateway

How to solve python POST response 405?

```
import requests
import json

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
myHeaders = { 'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Killbill-CreatedBy': 'demo', 'authorization':'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'X-Killbill-ApiKey': 'abcd', 'X-Killbill-ApiSecret': 'dcba'}

myData = {'transactionType': 'AUTHORIZE', 'amount': 23, 'currency': 'INR', 'transactionExternalKey': 'python003' }

myParams = {'paymentMethodId': '810d4eae-4668-4c6a-897c-178c041eb67f'}

response=requests.get(
    'http://192.168.12.80:8080/1.0/kb/accounts/a6c08c2c-f3eb-456a-a681-6e5262262e94',
    params = myParams,
    headers = myHeaders,
    data = json.dumps(myData),
)
print(response)
```

Comment: HTTP 405 means method not allowed. You said about python POST, but your code uses "response=requests.get(...". Try replacing that by line by "response=requests.post(...".

Answer (score 1):

405 status code response means the HTTP method you are trying is not allowed. Say, if a `PUT` request is not allowed on a server, it will reject the client's `PUT` request with an response code `405 Method not allowed`.

So, in your case also, the `POST` method might not be allowed on which you are sending the request and the request is simply denying you to make any `POST` request by sending `405` error response.